# TikZ reversed arrow wrong placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

When I place reversed arrow heads as decorations I can do it in two different ways.  The two ways place then at different positions, none of them is correct.  In the following code I use both of them, to make you see the different placements, but none of the placements is the symmetric version of the non-reversed arrowhead.  You can see it on the vertical axis.

I want the picture to be symmetric.  I can do it with breaking the paths in two parts.  Is there a slight modification of this code, that would make it symmetric? (manually changing .25 is not a good idea, since the paths have different lengths)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
  mark=at position .25 with {\arrowreversed{latex}},
  mark=at position .25 with {\arrow{latex reversed}},
  mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{latex}}}]
\clip (-3.2,-2.2) rectangle (3.2,2.2);
\draw[help lines] (-3.2,-2.2) grid (3.2,2.2);
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate}] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\foreach \c in {-2,-1.5,-1,-.2,1}{
  \pgfmathparse{.33*exp(\c/-6)}
  \draw[x=\pgfmathresult cm,postaction={decorate},smooth,samples at={-9,-7,...,9}] plot
  (\x,{\x*(ln(abs(\x)*\pgfmathresult)*2 + \c)*\pgfmathresult});}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[Here is the picture](http://www.math.bme.hu/~kanya/tikz-arrow.png)

---

(Added by Andrew Stacey):  Here's a minimal working example of the problem

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position .25 with {\arrowreversed{latex}}}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position .25 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}}] (0,-.2) -- (2,-.2);
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{latex}}}] (2,-.4) -- (0,-.4);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with result:

[image: reversed arrows]

The question is to get a syntax which lines up one of the first two arrows with the third (note the direction of drawing of the lines in each case: the third is in the reverse direction to the other two).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! You can always provide a link to your picture.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to provide a full minimum working example (MWE) that can be directly compiled without modification. I edited the code for you to add the preamble: if you notice some discrepancies you can always revert back to the original version. See also this question for more information on MWEs: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Tamas: I've taken the liberty of simplifying your code to get to the heart of the issue, but I added it rather than modifying what is already there.  Hope that's okay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a new arrow that's a combination of your original arrow head and an "empty arrow". That makes PGF throw away the `\pgfarrowsrightextend` and `\pgfarrowsleftextend` lengths that cause the offset with the original arrow heads. If you use these new arrow heads at the end of a line, they won't look very good because arrow heads need to extend a bit to fully cover the line underneath them (that's what the right and left extend is for).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{newlatex}{newlatex}{latex}{latex}{}{}

\draw[gray,thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{latex}}}] (2,0)  -- (0,0); % Original arrow
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrowreversed{newlatex}}}] (0,-.4)--  (2,-.4);
\draw[thick,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{newlatex}}}] (2,-.6)-- (0,-.6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: lines with arrow markings]