# Tikz - move/reposition arrow decorations (arrowhead length/size)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, lengths, decorations

I'm trying to build a 'dimension line' macro for Tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}

% note: with \documentclass{minimal}, this example fails with:
% ! Undefined control sequence.
% \pgf@lib@dec@computed@action ...t (0,0.25) {\tiny 
%                                                   {'test'}};}
% l.31 ...ne[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)]['test']
%                                                    ;
% ? 
% ... but if Enter is pressed at prompt, a PDF is generated anyways by pdflatex.. 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds,patterns,matrix,shapes,fit,calc,shadows,plotmarks,chains,positioning,scopes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
    %\node at (0,0) {"test: #1 - #2 ..."};
    \begin{scope}[>=latex] % redef arrow for dimension lines
        \draw[|-|,
            decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                mark=at position 0 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{<}};,
                mark=at position .5 with {\node[gray] at (0,0.25) {\tiny{#3}};},
                mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{>}};,
            },
        postaction={decorate},
        %shorten <=1pt,
        ] #1 -- #2 ;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) (nA) {A};
    \node at (3,0) (nB) {B};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)]['test'] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

... and almost everything works, except the left arrow gets extended to the left (I guess its reference point is at the right end?!).

[image: example rendering]

Obviously, I'd like the arrow moved to the right by the length of the arrow, but I cannot find anywhere how I could retrieve the size/length of the arrow?!

Other than that, are there any other ways to get the arrow to 'fit' inside the dimension line?

EDIT: Just to note: I'd like to keep `decoration={markings`, because I think only that allows me to scale the arrowhead, as in `\arrow[scale=0.5]`?!

Thanks,
Cheers!

Comment: Try the solution that Jake suggests in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/tikz-reversed-arrow-wrong-placement (I don't know if it will work or not as I haven't tried it yet, which is why I'm posting this as a comment)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Andrew Stacey! Funny, I was just looking at that question before I decided to post, and I thought at first it doesn't apply to me.. But I'm taking a second look now.. Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this application, you can just define a new combined arrowhead using `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{name left}{name right}{outer element left}{outer element right}{inner element left}{inner element right}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{|<}{>|}{|}{|}{latex}{latex}
\def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
    %\node at (0,0) {"test: #1 - #2 ..."};
    \begin{scope}[>=latex] % redef arrow for dimension lines
        \draw[|<->|,
        decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                mark=at position .5 with {\node[gray] at (0,0.25) {\tiny{#3}};},
        },
        postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) (nA) {A};
    \node at (3,0) (nB) {B};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)]['test'] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: measurement lines with tikz]

---

Or, in order to be able to scale the arrow tips at will, here's your approach with the decorations. The `latex` tips are combined with "empty arrows" to fix the protrusion over the end of the line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{dimarrow}{dimarrow}{latex}{latex}{}{}
\def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        \draw[|-|,
        decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
                mark=at position .5 with {\node[gray] at (0,0.25) {\tiny{#3}};},
                mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
            },
        postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) (nA) {A};
    \node at (3,0) (nB) {B};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)]['test'] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Jake, thanks a lot and +1 for your answer! However, I forgot to mention I want to keep 'decorations', because if I recall correctly, that is the only way to have a scaled (smaller/bigger) arrowhead than the default one? Yup, `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{|<}{>|}{|}{|}\arrow[scale=0.5]{<}\arrow[scale=0.5]{>}` fails..

Comment: @sdaau: Good point with the scaling. I've added a solution that uses your decorations approach. A neater version would probably be to dig into the source files of the arrow library and redefine proper new arrow tips using `pgfarrowsdeclare` based on the original arrows. This even allows you to parametrise the tips, e.g. if you want longer end lines (see pp. 610 in the [pgf manual](http://www.ctan.org/get/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf))

Comment: Thanks a million, @Jake, it works now :) First, sorry for not exactly reading your answer at first - you *were* using markings as well! However, the scaling was the main issue for me ... I was trying myself to cook up something - but I can see from your answer, I would have failed at the `\arrowreversed` step :) Fantastic - thanks again, wish I could +1 that answer once more :) Cheers!