# How to omit printing the decimal part in pgfmath macros

Tags: pgfmath

In [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz) a very nice solution to mark lengths on a drawing has been given that uses pgfmath's capability. How do I omit having the decimal part of the number printed, eg: 25 instead of 25.0?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the optional arguments of `\pgfmathprintnumber` to either cut off the decimal part or to round the number to an integer. Alternatively, you can use the `\num` macro from the `siunitx` package to round the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\testnumber{25.7}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\testnumber}

\pgfmathprintnumber[int trunc]{\testnumber}

\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\testnumber}

\num{\testnumber}

\num[round-mode=figures]{\testnumber}
\end{document}
```

[image: different rounding methods]

Comment: Yes it's the better way

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for the answer, but when I cut and paste the above example into a document, pdflatex can't typeset it. It returns: Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \pgfmathprintnumber

Comment: @Chah: You might have to update to a more recent version of PGF for this.

Comment: @Chah: Yes, it looks like you're using an outdated version of PGF. You can get the version number by inserting `\pgfversion` in your document; it should be at least v2.1.