# How to enforce printing the decimal part in pgfmath macros?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath, charts

I have the opposite problem to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19588/how-to-omit-printing-the-decimal-part-in-pgfmath-macros). I want the decimal parts of an integer printed for consistency's sake. I already tried specifying the `precision` but without success. See below. [image: an example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
nodes near coords, %={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
]
\addplot coordinates { (1,1.11) (2,2.22)(3,3.00)(4,4.44) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Follow up question in response to Peter Grill's answer:

Is it possible to let this specifications only affect the nodes over the bars and let the axis ticks stay without additional decimal parts? That would be the high point.

Answer:
By chance I already found the answer to that one myself. Setting

```
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/precision=0, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true }
```

to `0` and using

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
```

in the `axis`-specifications, I get "normal " integers on the axes and enforced decimal parts in the chart itself.

Comment: Your title asks about `pgfmath`, but your example is using `pgfplots`, which is not the same. Please change the title accordantly if this question is directly targeted on `pgfplots`, not `pgfmath` macros in general.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Of course I will change the title if it's flawed. Truth be told, my knowledge of `pgfplots` and `pgfmath` is basic at best. I encountered this problem by using `pgfplots` and deducted from posts such as the linked one that there must be something as `pgfmath` at work here. So if someone knows what the better title would be, please tell me and I'll change it accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need:

```
/pgf/number format/precision=1, 
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
}

\begin{axis}[ybar, nodes near coords]
\addplot coordinates { (1,1.11) (2,2.22)(3,3.00)(4,4.44) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. Would you happen to know the solution to my follow up question as well?

Comment: Never mind that, I already solved the follow up. Thanks again!