# Optimizing code for dimension arrows (CAD) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In Engineering it is customary  to denote small dimensions with arrows as shown below (in binding correction and trim top):

[image]

Variants exist such as

[image]

Currently they are all hardcoded as for example:

```
 \draw (0, \trystockheight@cx + 3mm) -- ++ (0,1cm)
       ++ (\lefttrim,-1cm) -- ++(0,1cm) ++(-1cm-\lefttrim,-0.5cm)[->,>=latex]
       -- ++(0.5cm+\lefttrim,0);  

 \draw (0, \trystockheight@cx + 3mm)
        ++ (0,0.5cm) -- ++ (\lefttrim,0)
        ++(1cm,0cm)[|->,>=latex]-- ++(-1cm,0cm)
        node[right] at ++(1cm,0)
        {\bindingcorrectionname\ \convert@cx{\lefttrim} $(\delta_b)$ };
```

What is an efficient was to generalize and draw such arrows, taking into account that labels can be left or right etc.

My apologies to anyone that might need a MWE, but the current code is quite longish to cut down to a minimal.

Comment: I am really looking forward to seeing your package!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It ballooned and is taking `\pi^2` longer than expected:).

Comment: @percusse We produce about 3000 A0 drgs a year:) Sometimes in technical illustrations yes, but I will edit.

Comment: Also maybe this would serve you good : [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to start an answer, here is the new arrow type inv. This will probably help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\pgfsetarrowoptions{inv}{10}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{inv}{inv}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{0\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0\pgflinewidth}
}{
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
  \pgfsetmiterjoin   % fix join
  \pgfsetroundcap    % fix cap
  % arrow
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.5\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4.5\pgflinewidth}{1.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4.5\pgflinewidth}{-1.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
  % amp
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgforigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfgetarrowoptions{inv} \pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  % mark
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  %
  \draw[line width=1pt,inv-inv]
  (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
  %
  \draw[line width=2pt,inv-inv]
  (0,1) -- (5,1);
  \fill[red] (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
  %
  {
    \pgfsetarrowoptions{inv}{15}
    \draw[line width=2pt,inv-inv]
    (0,2) -- (5,2);
  }
  \fill[red] (0,2) circle[radius=1pt];
  %
  \draw[blue,line width=3pt,inv-inv]
  (0,3) -- (5,3);
  \fill[red] (0,3) circle[radius=1.5pt];
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,dashed]{};
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=1.2cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one. One tiny detail: The standard engineering arrowheads are roughly assumed to have 1 unit of width 3 units of length.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for this information. I have changed my code to use this ratio.

Answer (score 10):

Recently, I needed to do this kind of drawing and that's what I used (I think I made a mix between codes from Jake, Martin and me. Missing cases where dimensions are small. I kept all the code to show the result. The third argument wit `dim`can b used to place the label (right, left etc.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ arrows,  calc,decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.text}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd, distance/.initial = 10pt}  

\pgfdeclaredecoration{add dim}{final}{
\state{final}{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/distance}}
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}             
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1.5*\dist}}   
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}} 
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{1.5*\dist}}     
          \pgfsetarrowsstart{latex}
          \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\dist}}
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{\dist}} 
          \pgfusepath{stroke} 
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}
}}

\tikzset{
    dim/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{%
                decoration = {add dim,distance=\ifx&#2&0pt\else#2\fi},
                decorate,
                postaction = {%
                   decorate,
                   decoration={%
                        raise=\ifx&#2&0pt\else#2\fi,
                        markings,
                        mark=at position .5 with {\node[inner sep=2pt,
                                                        font=\footnotesize,
                                                        fill=\ifx&#1&none\else white\fi,
                                                        #3] at (0,0) {#1};}
                   }
                }
    },
    dim/.default={,0pt,}
}   
\tikzset{add reference/.style={insert path={%
    coordinate [pos=0] (#1 south west) 
    coordinate [pos=1]   (#1 north east)
    coordinate [pos=.5] (#1 center)                        
    (#1 south west |- #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 north west)
    (#1 center     |- #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 north)
    (#1 center     |- #1 south west)     coordinate (#1 south)
    (#1 south west -| #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 south east)
    (#1 center     -| #1 south west)     coordinate (#1 west)
    (#1 center     -| #1 north east)     coordinate (#1 east)   
}}}    

 \tikzset{pt/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=4pt}}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path  (0,0)  coordinate  (O) 
       (5,8)  coordinate  (pt upper left);

\draw (O) rectangle (pt upper left)  [add reference=R];

\draw[dashed] (R north) --  (R south) 
              (R west) --   (R east);

\node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6pt,outer sep=1pt] (pt center) at (R center)   {};   
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6pt,outer sep=1pt] (pt base) at (0,2)  {};
\draw[dotted] (pt base) -- ++(7,0); 
\path[dim={totalheight,10ex,}]   (R north east) --  (R south east);
\path[dim={height,5ex,left}]         (R north east) --  (pt base -| R south east);
\path[dim={depth,5ex,}]          (pt base -| R south east) --  (R south east);
\path[dim={width,-4ex,}]         (R south west) --  (R south east);

\node[font=\footnotesize](line base) at (1.25,1){\emph{ligne de base}}; 
\draw [->,>=latex'] (line base) to [bend right](2,2);
\node[font=\footnotesize,text width=2cm](pt ref) at (-1.5,.5){\emph{point de\\référence}}; 
\draw [->,>=latex'] (pt ref) to [bend left](pt base); 
\node[font=\footnotesize](lines cent) at (1.25,6){\emph{lignes centrales}};
\draw [->,>=latex'] (lines cent) edge [bend right] (2.5,5)
                                 edge [bend right] (1.5,4);     
\node[font=\footnotesize](pt cent) at (4,3){\emph{point central}};
\draw [->,>=latex'] (pt cent) to [bend right](pt center);

\node[above]       at (R north)      {[\texttt{t}]};
\node[above left]  at (R north west) {[\texttt{lt}]}; 
\node[above right] at (R north east) {[\texttt{rt}]};

\node[below]       at (R south)      {[\texttt{b}]};
\node[below left]  at (R south west) {[\texttt{lb}]}; 
\node[below right] at (R south east) {[\texttt{rb}]};

\node[above right] at (R center)  {[\texttt{c}]};
\node[left]        at (R west)    {[\texttt{lc}]}; 
\node[right]       at (R east)    {[\texttt{rc}]};


\node[above right] at ([xshift=2.5cm]pt base)  {[\texttt{B}]};
\node[above left]        at (pt base)    {[\texttt{lB}]}; 
\node[above right]       at ([xshift=5cm]pt base)    {[\texttt{rB}]};     
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]