# Adding dimensions to TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How do you add dimension labels to TikZ pictures? Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
|<----- dimension ----->|
```

I would like to do this to show the measurement of both straight lines (i.e. sides of a polygon) and curved lines (i.e. circumference/arc length on a circle). Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you want the actual dimensions to be taken from the picture, or the "dimension" text is provided by you?

Comment: Please see [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14901), which should cover your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For educational and show-off purposes only!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{measure length/.style={
              decoration={markings,
              mark connection node=a,
              mark =at position 0.5 with {
                 \node[transform shape,fill=white,scale=0.5,#1] (a) 
                        {\pgfmathparse{\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2.845274}%
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]\pgfmathresult mm};},
             },
             postaction=decorate
       }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[measure length] (-2,-2cm) -- (2cm,-2cm);
\draw[measure length={rotate=180}] (0,0) arc (0:270:1cm) ;
\draw[measure length={rotate=180}] (0,3) arc (0:270:1cm) -- ++(10mm,0);

\foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
\draw[measure length] (2,2) +(\x*60:1cm) -- +({(\x+1)*60)}:1cm);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice, if this continues further we will replace 2D CAD with TikZ.

Comment: @Alexander I wish :-) But this is just showing off, under some pressure, it will disappoint you rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! One more thing though: is it possible to add arrows to the end of the lines?

Comment: @fctaylor25 Add `<->` in the `\draw` options.

Comment: Is there any way to make the measurement a variable (e.g. C for circumference, h for height, etc.)?

Comment: @fctaylor25 Not that I know of.

Comment: I ended up just doing the variable measurements "manually," using lines and arcs to draw the measurement lines.