# Move line by size of arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle together with the dimensions. Here is my first try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{4.0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\a, \b);
        \draw[|<->|] (0, 0) -- ++ (\a, 0); 
        \node[below] at (0.5*\a, 0) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rectangle]

This of course results in the line drawn on top of the rectangle, but I would like it to be a bit below. Sure, I could do something like

```
\draw[|<->|] (0, -5mm) -- ++ (\a, 0);
```

but this is neither very nice nor does it scale correctly. Any suggestions?

Edit: Heres is an example of what I mean by not scaling correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{4.0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\a, \b);
        \draw[|<->|] ([yshift=-1mm]0, 0) -- ++ (\a, 0); 
        \node[below] at (0.5*\a, 0) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\a, \b);
        \draw[|<->|] ([yshift=-1mm]0, 0) -- ++ (\a, 0); 
        \node[below] at (0.5*\a, 0) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two rectangles]

Comment: I've been looking for a long time for an automated way of doing this, I thought that a `measure` key would be great, with an optional distance, e.g., `\draw[measure] (0,0) -- (1,0);` automated, and `[measure=1cm]` in case one wants to decide the distance, but I don't know how to program it.

Comment: Yes that is sort of what I had in mind. Although simply `measure` won't do, because how would it know when to place it above, below, left or right? Regardless, my `tikz` foo is too weak, hence this question.

Comment: Yep, it's not perfect, I meant that something of this sort would be possible, ideally it would enable not only the distance (there's no above,below,left,right, you give two coordinates and then a shift), but also the label, and a few more things in my case.

Comment: Is this relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123913/adding-dimensions-to-tikz-pictures ? You can adjust the dimension presentation to an arrow rather than a node on the path.

Comment: Not quite, but http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz seems relevant. I'll take a look at that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a layman's workaround where we define a node at `(0,0)` and then draw the arrow from its south.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{4.0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) node[below] (A){} rectangle (\a, \b);
        \draw[|<->|] (A.south) -- ++ (\a, 0);
        \node[below] at (0.5*\a, 0) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \draw (0, 0) node[below] (A){} rectangle (\a, \b);
        \draw[|<->|] (A.south) -- ++ (\a, 0);
        \node[below] at (0.5*\a, 0) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can vary the distance by changing the `inner sep`

```
\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=1mm,below] (A){} rectangle (\a, \b);
```

[image]

Comment: But this is still a hardcoded number. If I were to scale the `tikzpicture`, the gap would change. On the contrary, the gap between the a and the rectangle stays the same, because of some magic in `\node[below]`, I presume.

Comment: @Psirus Can show show some code that it changes with scaling? I am not able to reproduce it. For example: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` doesn't do that.

Comment: @Psirus Now it isn't hardcoded. What you observed can be used.