# TikZ figure renders different when changing document class

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

When using `standalone` or `article` class, my TikZ figure renders as it should. But when changing to `tufte-handout`, I get some misalignments. Why is this? How can I solve it?

[image: With tufte-handout, wrong]

[image: With article class, ok]

The code of the figure in the following `MWE` is taken from the answer of @Tarass to this other question: [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz). At first I thought it was a problem with his `\Cote` command (as the cotes appeared to be completely messed), but removing all but the figure, revealed this misalignment with the circle.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{tufte-handout}
%\documentclass{article} %uncomment this to see what's happening
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!25]
        (0,1) coordinate (A)
    --  (3,1) coordinate (B)
    --  (5,2) coordinate (C)
    --  (5,4) coordinate (D)
    --  (3,4) coordinate (E)
    --  (2.5,3) coordinate (F)
    --  (2,4) coordinate (G)
    --  (0,4) coordinate (H)
    --cycle ;

\draw[red,fill=red!25] (2.5,3.9) circle (.39) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\small`...

Comment: Or put `\small` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` , not inside it.

Comment: Thanks. This `\small`was not so inoffensive at all...

Comment: This looks very much like a bug in `tufte-handout`: try inverting the order in which the `\draw` commands are issued (keeping `\small`).

Comment: @egreg Inverting the `draw`commands results even worse.

Comment: @PabloB. That's what I wanted to point out: it seems that adding `\small` in `tufte-handout` produces an awful lot of blank spaces or other junk.

Answer (score 5):

the class apparently sets up `\small` to set `\spaceskip` which seems wrong in general and is a disaster inside a `tikzpicture` You can avoid the problem by moving `\small` or you can reset `\spaceskip`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{tufte-handout}
%\documentclass{article} %uncomment this to see what's happening
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\spaceskip0pt
\draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!25]
        (0,1) coordinate (A)
    --  (3,1) coordinate (B)
    --  (5,2) coordinate (C)
    --  (5,4) coordinate (D)
    --  (3,4) coordinate (E)
    --  (2.5,3) coordinate (F)
    --  (2,4) coordinate (G)
    --  (0,4) coordinate (H)
    --cycle ;

\draw[red,fill=red!25] (2.5,3.9) circle (.39) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```