# How can I draw engineer dimensioning diagrams?

Tags: diagrams, engineering

How can I draw engineer dimensioning diagrams in LaTeX? For instance,

[image]

What I currently do is drawing the diagram in MS Visio, save as a pdf file and then embed it into LaTeX. (It is not easy to type mathematical formulas in Visio.)

Comment: Ti*k*Z, `pstricks`, `picture`, `pdfliteral`, etc., take your pick. See also [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205)

Comment: for a diagram this simple, why not use ipe instead of Visio?  It's free, and has good LaTeX support.

Comment: This will show you how to do the diagram dimensions and in the fourth answer there is a reference to a tikz packages so most of the work may be done for you already. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz

Comment: `(It is not easy to type mathematical formulas in visio)` I do this all the time, I also use Visio. like this: I open SW (scientific word) write my math in there, then select the math _as_picture_ from SW, and paste it on VISIO.  Here is an example [image](http://12000.org/my_notes/dynamics_cheat_sheet/3d_1_common_notation.png) and [another](http://12000.org/my_notes/dynamics_cheat_sheet/astro_drawings/parabolic_d1.png)  the math ofcourse will not be as good as native Latex code as with Tikz, but it is much easier to do and move the math around using the mouse, and one can resize it also ;)

Comment: @Mark thanks for IPE hint. I never knew about it, it looks really nice and it allows one to entry direct Latex code on the image. That is good suggestion. Will learn it also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `tikz-dimline` package will get you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \path   (0,0) coordinate (A)
            (4,0) coordinate (B)
            (12,0) coordinate (C)
            (16,0) coordinate (D)
            (0,2) coordinate (E)
            (4,2) coordinate (F)
            (16,2) coordinate (G);

    \draw[gray!10,fill=yellow] (E) rectangle (B) node[black] at ($(E)!.5!(B)$){bus1};
    \draw[gray!10,fill=red] (F) rectangle (C) node[black] at ($(F)!.5!(C)$){overlapping};
    \draw[gray!10,fill=green] (C) rectangle (G) node[black] at ($(C)!.5!(G)$){bus2};

    \dimline    [color=blue,
                line style={thick},
                extension start style={blue,thin},
                extension end style={blue,thin}
                ]{($(E)+(0,.5)$)}{($(G)+(0,.5)$)}{$t_c$};
    \dimline    [color=blue,
                line style={thick},
                extension start style={blue,thin},
                extension end style={blue,thin},
                extension start length=-1cm,
                extension end length=-1cm
                ]{($(A)-(0,.5)$)}{($(B)-(0,.5)$)}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$};
    \dimline    [color=blue,
                line style={thick},
                extension start style={blue,thin},
                extension end style={blue,thin},
                extension start length=-1cm,
                extension end length=-1cm
                ]{($(B)-(0,.5)$)}{($(C)-(0,.5)$)}{$t_{12}$};
    \dimline    [color=blue,
                line style={thick},
                extension start style={blue,thin},
                extension end style={blue,thin},
                extension start length=-1cm,
                extension end length=-1cm
                ]{($(C)-(0,.5)$)}{($(D)-(0,.5)$)}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using Tarass's excellent solution from [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz) will get you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    Cote node/.style={%
        midway,
        sloped,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        outer sep=2pt
    },
    Cote arrow/.style={%
        <->,
        >=latex,
        very thin
    }
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{%
    s               % cotation avec les flèches à l'extérieur
    D<>{1.5pt}      % offset des traits
    O{.75cm}        % offset de cotation
    m               % premier point
    m               % second point
    m               % étiquette
    D<>{o}          % () coordonnées -> angle
                    % h -> horizontal,
                    % v -> vertical
                    % o or what ever -> oblique
    O{}             % parametre du tikzset
}{%
    {%
        \tikzset{#8}

        \coordinate (@1) at #4 ;
        \coordinate (@2) at #5 ;

        \if #7v % Cotation verticale
            \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ; 
            \coordinate (@4) at (@0|-@1) ;
            \coordinate (@5) at (@0|-@2) ;
        \else
            \if #7h % Cotation horizontale
                \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (0,#3)$) ; 
                \coordinate (@4) at (@0-|@1) ;
                \coordinate (@5) at (@0-|@2) ;
            \else % cotation encoche
                \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
                    \coordinate (@5) at ($#7!#3!#5$) ;
                    \coordinate (@4) at ($#7!#3!#4$) ;
                \else % cotation oblique    
                    \coordinate (@5) at ($#5!#3!90:#4$) ;
                    \coordinate (@4) at ($#4!#3!-90:#5$) ;
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi

        \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@4) -- #4 ;
        \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@5) -- #5 ;

        \IfBooleanTF #1 {% avec étoile
            \draw[Cote arrow,-] (@4) -- (@5) node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
            \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@4) -- ($(@4)!-6pt!(@5)$) ;   
            \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@5) -- ($(@5)!-6pt!(@4)$) ;   
        }{% sans étoile
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
                \draw[Cote arrow] (@5) to[bend right] node[Cote node] {#6\strut} (@4) ;
            \else
                \draw[Cote arrow] (@4) -- (@5) node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path   (0,0) coordinate (A)
            (4,0) coordinate (B)
            (12,0) coordinate (C)
            (16,0) coordinate (D)
            (0,2) coordinate (E)
            (4,2) coordinate (F)
            (16,2) coordinate (G);

    \draw[gray!10,fill=yellow] (E) rectangle (B) node[black] at ($(E)!.5!(B)$){bus1};
    \draw[gray!10,fill=red] (F) rectangle (C) node[black] at ($(F)!.5!(C)$){overlapping};
    \draw[gray!10,fill=green] (C) rectangle (G) node[black] at ($(C)!.5!(G)$){bus2};

    \Cote{(E)}{(G)}{$t_c$}<h>
    \Cote{(A)}{(B)}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$}
    \Cote{(B)}{(C)}{$t_{12}$}
    \Cote{(C)}{(D)}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also in plain Metapost, with all the parameters at the top...

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate:="%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

c = 280;
t = 120;
h = 30;

path box[];
box1 = unitsquare xscaled 1/2(c-t) yscaled h;
box2 = unitsquare xscaled t yscaled h shifted point 1 of box1;
box3 = box1 shifted point 1 of box2;

fill box1 withcolor 0.8[red+green,white]; draw box1; label("bus1",        center box1);
fill box2 withcolor 0.8[red,white];       draw box2; label("overlapping", center box2);
fill box3 withcolor 0.8[green,white];     draw box3; label("bus2",        center box3);

path a[];
a1 = (point 0 of box1 -- point 1 of box1) shifted 12 down;
a2 = (point 0 of box2 -- point 1 of box2) shifted 12 down;
a3 = (point 0 of box3 -- point 1 of box3) shifted 12 down;
a4 = (point 3 of box1 -- point 2 of box3) shifted 12 up;

for i=1 upto 4:
  drawdblarrow a[i];
  draw (up--down) scaled 4 shifted point 0 of a[i];
  draw (up--down) scaled 4 shifted point 1 of a[i];
endfor

label.bot(btex $(t_c-t_{12})/2$ etex, point 1/2 of a1);
label.bot(btex $t_{12}$         etex, point 1/2 of a2);
label.bot(btex $(t_c-t_{12})/2$ etex, point 1/2 of a3);
label.top(btex $t_c$            etex, point 1/2 of a4);

endfig;
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `pstricks` solution, with a comparatively short code: I define three frame nodes, and connect them in varrious ways:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\psset{arrowinset=0.0, fillstyle=solid,}%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-2)(8.1,1.6)%
\pnodes(0,0){O}(8,0){A}(2.4,0){ry}(5.6,0){yg}%
\psset{linecolor=SteelBlue3}%
\psline(0,-2)(0,1.6)\psline(8,-2)(8,1.6)\psline(ry)(2.4,-2)\psline(yg)(5.6,-2)%
\psset{linewidth=0pt}%
 \fnode[framesize =2.4 1, fillcolor=Red1](1.2,0){b1}\fnode[framesize =3.2 1, fillcolor=Yellow1](4,0){ol}\fnode[framesize =2.4 1, fillcolor=Chartreuse4!80!](6.8,0){b2}%
 \psset{arrows=<->, offset=1, linewidth=0.8pt, nodesep =0pt}%
 \ncline{ry}{O}\naput{\color{SteelBlue3} $\mathsf{{(t_{\scriptscriptstyle C}-t_{\scriptscriptstyle 12})}/2} $}%
 \ncline{yg}{ry}\naput{\color{SteelBlue3} $\mathsf{t_{\scriptscriptstyle 12}} $}%
 \ncline{A}{yg}\naput{\color{SteelBlue3} $\mathsf{{(t_{\scriptscriptstyle C}-t_{\scriptscriptstyle 12})}/2} $}%
 \ncline{O}{A}\naput{\color{SteelBlue3} $\mathsf{t_{\scriptscriptstyle C}} $}%
 \rput(b1){bus1}\rput(b2){bus2}\rput(ol){overlapping}%
\end{pspicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple semi-automatic solution using `TiKZ`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document} \sffamily

\newcommand{\Dline}[4]{%
\path ($(#1)!#4!90:(#2)$)coordinate(a) ($(#2)!#4!-90:(#1)$)coordinate(b);
\draw[|<->|,shorten <=-.5\pgflinewidth,shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth] (a)--node[fill=white,sloped]{\small#3}(b);}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blk/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{minimum height=#1,minimum width=#,fill=#3,outer sep=0pt}, >=latex']    
\node(b1)[blk={1cm,3cm,yellow}]{bus1};
\node(ov)[blk={1cm,4cm,red},anchor=west] at(b1.east) {overlapping};
\node(b2)[blk={1cm,3cm,green},anchor=west] at(ov.east) {bus2};    
\Dline{b1.north west}{b2.north east}{$t_c$}{4mm}
\Dline{b1.south east}{b1.south west}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$}{4mm}
\Dline{ov.south east}{ov.south west}{$t_{12}$}{4mm}
\Dline{b2.south east}{b2.south west}{$(t_c-t_{12})/2$}{4mm}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]