# Replicating geometry drawing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get a picture like this:

[image]

However, I'm having trouble with having the lines spanning between the arrows and having the arrows go exactly to the widths in the picture. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz) is similar, but it fills the arrows with the actual lengths of the bars, instead of the `$y_2$` and `$y_1$` etc that I need.

Here is my MWE so far -- which is nothing close to what I need:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
  (3,0) coordinate (a) node[right] {$A_1$}
  -- (0,0) coordinate (b) 
  -- (-2,2) coordinate (c) node[above] {$A_2$}
  pic["$\alpha$",draw=MidnightBlue,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=0.8cm] {angle=a--b--c};
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](a,b){a}
    \tkzLabelSegment[left=2pt](b,c){b}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code results in:

[image]

Comment: The example image looks very different from the one you made, are you trying to make an exact copy or simply using ideas from that image?

Comment: Hi @Alenanno, yes I'm trying to replicate that image exactly, I just put an MWE to show my "skills" or knowledge of how to use TikZ so far, as I really don't know how to do this. Even if someone could show me some examples I'd be grateful, as I've googled and searched and found nothing close enough :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to give you half of it, but I decided to do it all, also because once the half was done, the other half is almost the same, except for some differences.

The "rectangles" are actually done horizontally, but they are enclosed in a scope and this last one rotated, see `\begin{scope}[rotate around={30:(O)}]`. I think it's easier this way.

The angle is automatically drawn. So to change it, change the rotation of the rectangles.

If something is unclear, feel free to ask in the comments.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

% Upper "rectangle"
\begin{scope}[rotate around={30:(O)}]
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (3,0) coordinate (a);
\draw[ultra thick] (a) -- (5,0) coordinate (b) node[midway, below] {$A_2$};

\draw (O) -- (0,2);
\draw (a) --++ (0,1);
\draw (b) --++ (0,2);

\draw[-{Latex}] (0,.5) -- (0,.5-|a) node[midway, fill=white] {$y_1$};
\draw[-{Latex}] (0,1.5) -- (0,1.5-|b) node[near end, fill=white] {$y_2$};
\end{scope}

% Lower "rectangle"
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-15:(O)}]
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (3.5,0) coordinate (x);
\draw[ultra thick] (x) -- (5.5,0) coordinate (y) node[midway, above] {$A_1$};

\draw (O) -- (0,-2);
\draw (x) --++ (0,-1);
\draw (y) --++ (0,-2);

\draw[-{Latex}] (0,-.5) -- (0,-.5-|x) node[midway, fill=white] {$x_1$};
\draw[-{Latex}] (0,-1.5) -- (0,-1.5-|y) node[near end, fill=white] {$x_2$};
\end{scope}

% Angle (automatic)
\path (b) -- (O) -- (y) 
  pic["$\alpha$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=2cm] {angle=y--O--b};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I really appreciate this!

Comment: I did have one question, how did you get the lines between the arrows? What part of the code generates those lines?

Comment: @Alborz which lines are you referring to? The ones that touch the arrow tips?

Comment: yes exactly, that emanate from the ends of A1 and A2 upwards

Comment: @Alborz for example: `\draw (a) --++ (0,1); \draw (b) --++ (0,2);`

Comment: @Alborz No problem!