# Drawing a diagram with arc and angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, arc, angle

I am new to LaTeX. I need to draw the following in TikZ or PSTricks. But TikZ is preferable.

[image]

Comment: What did  you try or did find?

Comment: How is it possible to vote 8 times for an answer and not vote for the question? 
As @egreg says, if the question deserves an answer, doesn't it deserve a vote?https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/why-do-top-users-on-this-site-have-such-high-reputations/6692#6692

Comment: @AndréC: An upvote indicates research effort and usefulness to other users. This question is more of a "please do this for me" request. OP should make an attempt with a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or at least cite other questions that have parts of the diagram that are similar. Google "tikz angle" and many examples come up.

Comment: @SandyG This shows that the points system is not fully developed and needs to be improved. If each answer automatically assigned a vote to the question, those who answer questions that they feel are not worth a vote would abstain from answering.

Answer (score 9):

A `pstricks` solution, based od the `pst-eucl` module:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
% \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} for use with pdflatex --enablewrite18 (MiKTeX)
% or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3, dotsize = 3pt, shortput = nab}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.5)(1,1.5)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle = {-90,30,90,150}, PointName = {A, \rlap{$B_1\;(x_{b_1}{,}y_{b_1})$}, B, \llap{$(x_{b_2}{,}y_{b_2})\; B_2$}}, PointNameSep = 0.8em]
(0,0){A}(1; 65){B1}(1; 90){B}(1; 115){B2}
\uput{1.5em}[d](A){$ (x_ a ,y_a) $}
\uput{1.5em}[u](B){$ (x_ b ,y_b) $}
\pstArcOAB{A}{B1}{B2}
\ncline{A}{B}
\psline[linestyle = dashed, linewidth = 0.5pt](B1)(A)(B2)
\ncline[arrows = |<->|, offset = 10pt]{A}{B2}^{$ R $}
\psarc[linewidth = 0.5pt](A){0.25}{65}{90}\uput{0.3}[75](A){$\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\pstMarkAngle` can simplify your code.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: HappyNew Year! That's what I tried first, but it didn't work, for some reason. Does it for you? Anyway, I can't test anew, as the latest pstricks seems to have a bug.

Comment: Happy New Year too! I will try in a couple of seconds. DONE!

Comment: Fine! Just a last question: did you update pstricks to v. 2.80a? I have problems with this version and I suspect my problem with \pstMarkAngle might be linked.

Comment: Not yet. I will try updating later.

Answer (score 7):

While waiting for a `tikz` solution after more details from the OP's previous attempts are given, the try below shows it can be a job for MetaPost as well. Code included in a LuaLaTeX program.

**Update** To prevent [the Metafun bug discovered by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408215/metafun-why-is-the-arrow-tip-not-filled) in the most recent TeX distributions, bug which produces empty arrow heads instead of the expected filled ones (see also the comments here below), I've loaded the [`mparrows`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mparrows) package and set its `setarrows` parameter to `default`. This prevents the problem to appear.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u = 1.25cm; R = 3u; t = 25; 
input mparrows; setarrows(default);
beginfig(1);
    pair A, B, B[];
    A = origin; B = R*dir 90; B1 = B rotated -t; B2 = B rotated t; 
    draw B1 .. B .. B2; 
    draw A -- B; for P = B1, B2: draw A--P dashed evenly; endfor;
    for P = A, B, B1, B2: drawdot P withpen pencircle scaled 3bp; endfor;
    draw anglebetween(A--B1, A--B, btex $\theta$ etex);
    label.bot(btex $\begin{array}{c} A\\ (x_a, y_a) \end{array}$ etex, A);
    label.top(btex $\begin{array}{c} (x_b, y_b)\\ B \end{array}$ etex, B);
    path radius; radius = (A -- B2) shifted (.18u * unitvector B2 rotated 90);
    drawdblarrow radius; label.lft(btex $R$ etex, point .5 of radius);
    freelabeloffset := 5bp;
    freelabel(btex $B_1(x_{b_1}, y_{b_1})$ etex, B1, A);
    freelabel(btex $(x_{b_2}, y_{b_2})B_2$ etex, B2, A);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would shift down the arrow a bit. Do you have an idea why I don't get black filled arrow tips with your code?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right about the arrow, I've just shifted it down. About the arrow tips, I've no idea at all, it's the first time I hear about this problem. Strange!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I've just slightly changed the shifting of the arrow: it is now shifted along the direction orthogonal to the A--B2 radius, as Marmot did below. It seems the right way to do it.

Comment: Yes looks better. And I really get a non-filled arrow tip with metafun -- I'm at loss why, I think I will ask a question ;-).

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? I just realized that it works in TL15 but not in TL16 and TL17.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes I think, I use MacTeX 2017, based on TL 2017. Maybe it is something concerning the viewer?

Comment: Perhaps you have some older files in your local texmf?

Comment: I've just checked. No… I guess your problem is one for the MetaPost mailing list and its experts!

Answer (score 6):

With Ti*k*Z. **UPDATE**: Shifted the double arrow by `(-0.5 \cos\theta,-0.5 \sin\theta)`, thanks to Sigur.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (110:5);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (70:5);
\draw (0,5) arc (90:110:5) node [left,yshift=1.5mm] {$(x_{b2},y_{b2})~B_2$};
\draw (0,5) arc (90:70:5) node [right] {$B_1~(x_{b1},y_{b1})$};
\draw[-] node [below] {$\begin{array}{c}A\\ (x_a,y_a)\end{array}$} (0,0) -- (0,5) node [above] {$\begin{array}{c} (x_b,y_b)\\ B\end{array}$};
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1.5) arc (90:70:1.5) node[above,midway] {$\theta$};
\draw[latex-latex,transform canvas={xshift=-0.2165cm,yshift=-0.125em},thick] (0,0) -- (110:5)
node[left,midway] {$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. But it would be better if the `R` arrow has length smaller, showing the radius. It is a little bit longer (maybe pointing to `B_2` label).

Comment: @sigur I'm not sure I understand what I mean. The double arrow has precisely the same length as the dashed lines.

Comment: Make the arc longer to left side and it should *tangent* the arrow. But it looks like going to cross the arrow.

Comment: @Sigur Shifted the arrow correctly (I think). Thanks! However, I do not think that the continuation of the arc should hit the arrow at its tip. Rather, one should shift by `-r (\cos \theta,\sin\theta)`, I think.

Comment: This could help you to understand what I mean: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14901/14757

Comment: @Sigure Yes, it supports what I did. Look at the arrow labelled 2 in the accepted answer. The arrow is shifted in the direction orthogonal to the line the length of which it should indicate. I did the same.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying Bernard's code for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\psset{shortput = nab}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,5)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-90,30,90,150},PointName={A, \rlap{$B_1\;(x_{b_1}{,}y_{b_1})$}, B, \llap{$(x_{b_2}{,}y_{b_2})\; B_2$}}, PointNameSep=12pt]
(0,0){A}(3; 65){B1}(3; 90){B}(3; 115){B2}
\uput{1.5em}[d](A){$ (x_ a ,y_a) $}
\uput{1.5em}[u](B){$ (x_ b ,y_b) $}
\pstArcOAB{A}{B1}{B2}
\ncline{A}{B}
\psline[linestyle = dashed, linewidth = 0.5pt](B1)(A)(B2)
\ncline[arrows = |<->|, offset = 10pt]{A}{B2}^{$ R $}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=1.5]{B1}{A}{B}{$\theta$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]