# metafun: Why is the arrow tip not filled?

Tags: luatex, lua, metafun

Trying out another example I saw that with the metafun format (luatex version) the arrow tips are no longer filled. The following document (to be compile with lualatex) shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have the problem on windows with TeXlive 2016, 2017 and miktex. In TeXlive 2015 it worked correctly. If I copy the metafun files from `texlive\2017\texmf-dist\metapost\context` to texlive 2015 it fails there too.

Can someone reproduce the problem and has an idea what could be the source?

### Edit

I identified a problematic definition in `mp-tool.mpiv` (but I don't know yet why the fillup doesn't work, in context there seem to be no problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin{mplibcode}
def mfun_draw_arrow_path text t =
    if autoarrows :
        set_ahlength(t) ;
    fi
    draw arrowpath mfun_arrow_path t ;
    fill arrowhead mfun_arrow_path t ; %changed fillup to fill
    endgroup ;
enddef ;
beginfig(1);
drawarrow (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit 2

Imho some important code is missing (my guess is that in context it is in mlib-pdf.lua) and so luamplib needs to be updated.

### Edit 3

On the metapost mailing list, Hans Hagen confirm that new code is needed. He wrote

> i have added some code to the luatex-mplib.lua module and it works in 
>   plain now so when i post a new context beta someone has to make sure 
>   it's also used in latex

and I added an issue to https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues/71

Comment: Same problem here using TeXlive 2017 on Linux Mint 18.

Comment: You were previously right. I had some old Metafun files in my home `texmf` (don't remember how they landed there). I've just removed them and now I've got the same problem as you, with TeX Live 2017 (MacTeX)…

Comment: Not an idea about the source of the problem, but here is a workaround: to use the `mparrows` package and issue the `setarrows(default);` command. The arrow head is then filled, as it should. http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/mparrows/mparrows.pdf

Comment: I took the liberty to send a message to the MetaPost mailing list, telling them about this problem. I'm curious about the answers…

Comment: @FranckPastor I added an edit. (and I wished I wouldn't always loose the c in my name ;-))

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I loose the c in my surname quite as often ;-) By the way, I will soon write to the MetaPost mailing list about this `fillup`macro.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My first name, I meant! As for the MetaPost mailing list, I've sent the message mentioned above.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wonder if the current maintainer of the `luamplib` package still has enough time to spend on it, since there is one pending issue dating from September that has apparently not been handled since. We'll see.

Comment: @FranckPastor there seems to be at least a temporary fix: https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues/71

Comment: I've just installed it and it seems to work. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a bug which has since been fixed.