# Dimensioning of a drawing stops working with some label package options

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, dimensions

I want to dimensioning a drawing with [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz), this includes angles. I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180110/203837) that worked pretty well for me, but when I include the babel package in my document, there were some problems, this is the code that works well (with some changes to the [original](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180110/203837) code):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\tikzset{%
    Cote node/.style={
        midway,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        outer sep=2pt
    },
    Cote arrow/.style={
        <->,
        >=latex,
        very thin
    }
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{
    s       % dimensioning with arrows outside
    D<>{1.5pt} % line offset
    O{.75cm}    % dimension offset
    m       % first point
    m       % second point
    m       % label
    D<>{o}  % () coordinates -> angle
            % h -> horizontal,
            % v -> vertical
            % or whatever -> oblique
    O{}     % tikzset parameter
    }{

    {\tikzset{#8}

    \coordinate (@1) at #4 ;
    \coordinate (@2) at #5 ;

    \if #7H % dimension horizontal line
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5+(#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4+(#3,0)$) ;
    \else
    \if #7V % dimension vertical line
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5+(0,#3)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4+(0,#3)$) ;
    \else
    \if #7v % vertical dimension
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at (@0|-@1) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at (@0|-@2) ;
    \else
    \if #7h % horizontal dimension
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (0,#3)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at (@0-|@1) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at (@0-|@2) ;
    \else % concave dimensioning
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#7!#3!#5$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#7!#3!#4$) ;
    \else % oblique dimension
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5!#3!90:#4$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4!#3!-90:#5$) ;
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi

    \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@4) -- #4 ;
    \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@5) -- #5 ;

    \IfBooleanTF #1 {% with star
    \draw[Cote arrow,-] (@4) -- (@5)
        node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
    \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@4) -- ($(@4)!-6pt!(@5)$) ;
    \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@5) -- ($(@5)!-6pt!(@4)$) ;
    }{% without star
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        \draw[Cote arrow] (@5) to[bend right]
            node[Cote node] {#6\strut} (@4) ;
    \else
    \draw[Cote arrow] (@4) -- (@5)
        node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
    \fi
    }}
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \small
    \draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!25]
            (0,1) coordinate (A)
        --  (3,1) coordinate (B)
        --  (5,2) coordinate (C)
        --  (5,4) coordinate (D)
        --  (3,4) coordinate (E)
        --  (2.5,3) coordinate (F)
        --  (2,4) coordinate (G)
        --  (0,4) coordinate (H)
        --cycle ;

    \draw[red,fill=red!25] (2.5,3.9) circle (.39) ;

    \Cote{(A)}{(B)}{1 m}

    \Cote{(B)}{(C)}{2 m}[red]

    \Cote[.3cm]{(B)}{(C)}{2}[%
        red,Cote node/.append style={sloped}]

    \Cote{(B)}{(C)}{2 bis}<h>[Cote node/.append style={fill=blue!25}]

    \Cote[.3cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3 bis}[%
            Cote node/.append style={rotate=90}]
    \Cote[.7cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3}
    \Cote[1.1cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3 ter}[%
                Cote node/.append style={right}]

    \Cote[2cm]{(G)}{(E)}{45$^\circ$}<(F)>

    \Cote*[1.2cm]{(2.11,3.9)}{(2.89,3.9)}{4}[%
        Cote node/.append style={fill=blue!25}]

    \Cote[-2cm]{(A)}{(2.5,4.29)}{5}<v>

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this generates:

[image]

But when I change:

`\usepackage{babel}`

for:

`\usepackage[spanish, es-nodecimaldot, es-tabla]{babel}`

I get:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?, I'm using pdflatex, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Ti*k*Z library babel.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish, es-nodecimaldot, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc} %<- added babel
\usepackage{xparse}
\tikzset{%
    Cote node/.style={
        midway,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        outer sep=2pt
    },
    Cote arrow/.style={
        <->,
        >=latex,
        very thin
    }
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{
    s       % dimensioning with arrows outside
    D<>{1.5pt} % line offset
    O{.75cm}    % dimension offset
    m       % first point
    m       % second point
    m       % label
    D<>{o}  % () coordinates -> angle
            % h -> horizontal,
            % v -> vertical
            % or whatever -> oblique
    O{}     % tikzset parameter
    }{

    {\tikzset{#8}

    \coordinate (@1) at #4 ;
    \coordinate (@2) at #5 ;

    \if #7H % dimension horizontal line
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5+(#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4+(#3,0)$) ;
    \else
    \if #7V % dimension vertical line
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5+(0,#3)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4+(0,#3)$) ;
    \else
    \if #7v % vertical dimension
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (#3,0)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at (@0|-@1) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at (@0|-@2) ;
    \else
    \if #7h % horizontal dimension
        \coordinate (@0) at ($($#4!.5!#5$) + (0,#3)$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at (@0-|@1) ;
        \coordinate (@5) at (@0-|@2) ;
    \else % concave dimensioning
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#7!#3!#5$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#7!#3!#4$) ;
    \else % oblique dimension
        \coordinate (@5) at ($#5!#3!90:#4$) ;
        \coordinate (@4) at ($#4!#3!-90:#5$) ;
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi

    \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@4) -- #4 ;
    \draw[very thin,shorten >= #2,shorten <= -2*#2] (@5) -- #5 ;

    \IfBooleanTF #1 {% with star
    \draw[Cote arrow,-] (@4) -- (@5)
        node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
    \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@4) -- ($(@4)!-6pt!(@5)$) ;
    \draw[Cote arrow,<-] (@5) -- ($(@5)!-6pt!(@4)$) ;
    }{% without star
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#7\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        \draw[Cote arrow] (@5) to[bend right]
            node[Cote node] {#6\strut} (@4) ;
    \else
    \draw[Cote arrow] (@4) -- (@5)
        node[Cote node] {#6\strut};
    \fi
    }}
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \small
    \draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!25]
            (0,1) coordinate (A)
        --  (3,1) coordinate (B)
        --  (5,2) coordinate (C)
        --  (5,4) coordinate (D)
        --  (3,4) coordinate (E)
        --  (2.5,3) coordinate (F)
        --  (2,4) coordinate (G)
        --  (0,4) coordinate (H)
        --cycle ;

    \draw[red,fill=red!25] (2.5,3.9) circle (.39) ;

    \Cote{(A)}{(B)}{1 m}

    \Cote{(B)}{(C)}{2 m}[red]

    \Cote[.3cm]{(B)}{(C)}{2}[%
        red,Cote node/.append style={sloped}]

    \Cote{(B)}{(C)}{2 bis}<h>[Cote node/.append style={fill=blue!25}]

    \Cote[.3cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3 bis}[%
            Cote node/.append style={rotate=90}]
    \Cote[.7cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3}
    \Cote[1.1cm]{(C)}{(D)}{3 ter}[%
                Cote node/.append style={right}]

    \Cote[2cm]{(G)}{(E)}{45$^\circ$}<(F)>

    \Cote*[1.2cm]{(2.11,3.9)}{(2.89,3.9)}{4}[%
        Cote node/.append style={fill=blue!25}]

    \Cote[-2cm]{(A)}{(2.5,4.29)}{5}<v>

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh how fast!, thanks so much @Schrödinger's cat, it's already several times that you save me!...

Comment: @4lrdyD You're welcome!