# Are there simple ways to draw measurement of length of a line in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The "measurement of length of a line" in my question is the part highlighted by a green rectangle in the following figure:
[image]

Now, I am drawing the elements (i.e. two arrows, two ends, 8) of the measurement separately. It is tedious. I wonder are there simple ways to draw these measurements? For example, `\somecommand [<->, offset=x mm, "text"] (point1) -- (point2)`, namely `\somecommand [<->, offset=2mm, "4"] (A) -- (D)` or `\somecommand [<->, offset=2mm, "8"] (B) -- (C)` in the above figure. I would appreciate any help with this situation.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz can help? (there is a pakage too, https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-dimline?lang=en)

Comment: Dear @Rmano: This information is very useful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd be interested, it uses a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[ border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}%,

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(8.5,4.5)
    \psset{ labelsep=0.8ex, linejoin=1, RightAngleSize=0.25, tbarsize=8pt, arrowinset=0.1}
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PosAngle={180,180,0,0}](3,4){A}(0,0){B}(8,0){C}(7,4){D}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)(D)(A)%
    \pnodes{H}(4,4)(4,0)\pcline(H0)(H1)\ncput*{4}
    \pstRightAngle{D}{H0}{H1} \pstRightAngle{C}{H1}{H0}
    \psset{offset=1.6ex}
    \pcline{|<->|}(A)(D)\ncput*{4} \pcline{|<->|}(C)(B)\ncput*{8}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]