# Microstrip line drawing using TikZ - dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am struggling with a drawing simple schematic *microstrip line* (see [example](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/microstrip-filters-for/9781118002124/OEBPS/images/c04f001.jpg)).

What I have already done is solid body, but shadings are not well made (suggestions are as well welcome). The main problem is with using engeneering dimension signs. I used parts of Jakes code here [Tikz - move/reposition arrow decorations (arrowhead length/size)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12296/tikz-move-reposition-arrow-decorations-arrowhead-length-size/#12297)
but it still results in messed up and say ugly picture.

I have no idea how to make it look more professional, I would be grateful if anyone can improve my enclosed code bellow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.markings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%% please note changes in color %%
\definecolor{whitesmoke}{rgb}{0.90, 0.90, 0.90}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.73, 0.73, 0.73}
\definecolor{dimgray}{rgb}{0.51, 0.51, 0.51}
\definecolor{pearl}{rgb}{0.94, 0.92, 0.84}
\definecolor{antiflashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\begin{document}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{dimarrow}{dimarrow}{latex}{latex}{}{}
\def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        \draw[|-|,
        decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
                mark=at position .5 with {\node[black] at (0,0.25) {#3};},
                mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
            },
        postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [white](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (5,1,0) -- (5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);

\filldraw [whitesmoke] (0,0,5) -- (0,1,5) -- (5,1,5) -- (5,0,5) -- (0,0,5);

\shade[left color = white, right color = lightgray] (0,1,0) -- (5,1,0) -- (5,1,5) -- (0,1,5) -- (0,1,0);

\filldraw [dimgray] (5,0,0) -- (5,0,5) -- (5,1,5) -- (5,1,0);

\filldraw [lightgray] (0,0,5) -- (5,0,5) -- (5,0,0) -- (5,-0.2,0) -- (5,-0.2,5) -- (0,-0.2,5);


\filldraw [white] (1.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1,5) -- (1.5,1,5) -- cycle;

\filldraw [lightgray] (1.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1,5) -- (1.5,1,5) -- cycle;

\shade [left color = white, right color = whitesmoke] (1.5,1.2,0) -- (3.5,1.2,0) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (1.5,1.2,5) -- cycle;

\filldraw [lightgray] (3.5,1,5) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1.2,0) -- (3.5,1,0) -- cycle;

\node at (4,0.5,5) {$\varepsilon$};

\node at (1.5,1.5,0) (nA) {};
    \node at (3.5,1.5,0) (nB) {};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)][$w$];
\draw (1.5,2.5,0) -- (1.5,1.3,0);
\draw (3.5,2.5,0) -- (3.5,1.3,0);


\node at (-1.5,0.2,0) (nA) {};
    \node at (-1.5,0.2,5) (nB) {};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)][$l$][left];
\draw (-1.5,1.2,5) -- (1.4,1.2,5);
\draw (-1.5,1.2,0) -- (1.4,1.2,0); 

\node at (7,0,5) (nA) {};
    \node at (7,0.2,5) (nB) {};
    \Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)][$t$][left];
\draw (7,1.2,5) -- (3.6,1.2,5);
\draw (7,1,5) -- (3.6,1,5);      

\node at (-1.5,0,5) (nA) {};
\node at (-1.5,-1,5) (nB) {};
\Dimline[($(nA)+(0,1)$)][($(nB)+(0,1)$)][$h$][left];   
\draw (-1.5,1,5) -- (-0.1,1,5);
\draw (-1.5,0,5) -- (-0.1,0,5);

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed the two inline text to make the example copy pastable.

Comment: I would make the lines with arrows thicker and the lines without arrows thinner and much shorter.  I would also avoid shading all the way to white, which is essentially invisible.  You realize that with undocumented code about the only way to figure out what the code is doing is to change the colors and see what happens.

Comment: You obviously aren't trying to copy the example diagram you linked to, so what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: The first line is pointless unless you have a coloured background: a white rectangle on a white page. Even if you colour it, most of it is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to draw the picture.

I defined base color for the copper and the PCB and then used `\colorlet` to define different shades of these for different elements. From `\Dimline` I removed `|-|`, because the short lines look wrong for *l*. For the markings I defined coordinates in the drawing commands (similar to cfrs answer). And for `\shade` the option `shading angle` is used to rotate the shading so its parallel to the sides.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.markings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%% please note changes in color %%
% base color for copper and PCB
\definecolor{copper}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{pcb}{rgb}{0,1,0}
% shades of them for the different elements
\colorlet{groundplane}{copper!50!black}
\colorlet{pcbfront}{pcb!50!black}
\colorlet{pcbright}{pcb!20!black}
\colorlet{pcbtopleft}{pcb!70!black}
\colorlet{pcbtopright}{pcb!50!black}
\colorlet{striplinefront}{copper!50!black}
\colorlet{striplineright}{copper!50!black}
\colorlet{striplinetopleft}{copper!90!black}
\colorlet{striplinetopright}{copper!60!black}

\begin{document}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{dimarrow}{dimarrow}{latex}{latex}{}{}
\def\Dimline[#1][#2][#3]{
        \draw[ % |-|, % removed, looks odd for l
        decoration={markings, % switch on markings
                mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
                mark=at position .5 with {\node[black] at (0,0.25) {#3};},
                mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
            },
        postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% PCB back, not visible, so it can be skiped
%\filldraw [white](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (5,1,0) -- (5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);

% PCB front, use cycle to close path
\filldraw [pcbfront] (0,0,5) coordinate (height bottom) -- (0,1,5) coordinate (height top) -- (5,1,5) -- (5,0,5) -- cycle;

% PCB top
\shade[top color = pcbtopleft, bottom color = pcbtopright, shading angle=75] (0,1,0) -- (5,1,0) -- (5,1,5) -- (0,1,5) -- cycle;

% PCB right, closed it
\filldraw [pcbright] (5,0,0) -- (5,0,5) -- (5,1,5) -- (5,1,0) -- cycle;

% groundplane
\filldraw [groundplane] (0,0,5) -- (5,0,5) -- (5,0,0) -- (5,-0.2,0) -- (5,-0.2,5) -- (0,-0.2,5) -- cycle;

% stripline front
\filldraw [striplinefront] (1.5,1.2,5) coordinate (length front) -- (3.5,1.2,5) coordinate (thickness top) -- (3.5,1,5) coordinate (thickness bottom) -- (1.5,1,5) -- cycle;

% stripline front, duplicate
%\filldraw [lightgray] (1.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1,5) -- (1.5,1,5) -- cycle;

%stripline top
\shade [top color = striplinetopleft, bottom color = striplinetopright, shading angle=75] (1.5,1.2,0) coordinate (width left) coordinate (length back) -- (3.5,1.2,0) coordinate (width right)  -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (1.5,1.2,5) -- cycle;

% stripline right
\filldraw [striplineright] (3.5,1,5) -- (3.5,1.2,5) -- (3.5,1.2,0) -- (3.5,1,0) -- cycle;

\node at (4,0.5,5) {$\varepsilon$};

% nodes no longer needed
%\node at (1.5,1.5,0) (nA) {};
%\node at (3.5,1.5,0) (nB) {};
% stripline width
\Dimline[($(width left)+(0,1,0)$)][($(width right)+(0,1,0)$)][$w$];
\draw ($(width left)+(0,0.1,0)$) -- ($(width left)+(0,1.1,0)$);
\draw ($(width right)+(0,0.1,0)$) -- ($(width right)+(0,1.1,0)$);

% nodes no longer needed
%\node at (-1.5,0.2,0) (nA) {};
%\node at (-1.5,0.2,5) (nB) {};
% stripline length
\Dimline[($(length back)+(-2.5,0,0)$)][($(length front)+(-2.5,0,0)$)][$l$]; %[left];
\draw ($(length front)+(-0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(length front)+(-2.6,0,0)$);
\draw ($(length back)+(-0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(length back)+(-2.6,0,0)$); 

% nodes no longer needed
%\node at (7,0,5) (nA) {};
%\node at (7,0.2,5) (nB) {};
% stripline thickness
\Dimline[($(thickness top)+(3.5,0,0)$)][($(thickness bottom)+(3.5,0,0)$)][$t$]; %[left];
\draw ($(thickness top)+(0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(thickness top)+(3.6,0,0)$);
\draw ($(thickness bottom)+(0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(thickness bottom)+(3.6,0,0)$);      

% nodes no longer needed
%\node at (-1.5,0,5) (nA) {};
%\node at (-1.5,-1,5) (nB) {};
% PCB height
\Dimline[($(height top)+(-1,0,0)$)][($(height bottom)+(-1,0,0)$)][$h$]; %[left];   
\draw ($(height top)+(-0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(height top)+(-1.1,0,0)$);
\draw ($(height bottom)+(-0.1,0,0)$) -- ($(height bottom)+(-1.1,0,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly I was looking for. Inteligent and clear code with nice result. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if the result is better or worse, but the code is somewhat cleaner, I think. At least, it is simpler.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning}
\definecolor{whitesmoke}{rgb}{0.90, 0.90, 0.90}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.73, 0.73, 0.73}% overrides default?
\definecolor{dimgray}{rgb}{0.51, 0.51, 0.51}

\begin{document}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{dimarrow}{dimarrow}{latex}{latex}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand\Dimline { m m o } {
  \draw[|-|, thick, shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth, shorten <=-.5\pgflinewidth,
  decoration={markings, % switch on markings
    mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
    mark=at position .5 with {\IfValueT{#3}{\node [black, fill=white] {#3};}},
    mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{dimarrow}};,
  },
  postaction=decorate] #1 -- #2 ;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [lightgray] (0,1,0) coordinate (bl) -- (5,1,0) coordinate (br);
  \filldraw [whitesmoke] (0,0,5) coordinate (fll) -- (0,1,5) coordinate (ftl) -- (5,1,5) coordinate (ftr) -- (5,0,5) coordinate (flr) -- cycle;
  \shade [left color = whitesmoke, right color = lightgray] (bl) -- (br) -- (ftr) -- (ftl) -- cycle;
  \filldraw [dimgray] (5,0,0) coordinate (blr) -- (flr) -- (ftr) -- (br);
  \filldraw [lightgray] (fll) rectangle (5,-0.2,5) coordinate (flr2);
  \filldraw [darkgray] (flr2) -- (5,-0.2,0) coordinate (blr2) -- (blr) -- (flr) -- cycle;
  \filldraw [lightgray] (1.5,1.2,5) coordinate (ftl-1) -- (3.5,1.2,5) coordinate (ftr-1) -- (3.5,1,5) coordinate (flr-1) -- (1.5,1,5) coordinate (fll-1) -- cycle;
  \shade [left color = whitesmoke!50, right color = whitesmoke] (1.5,1.2,0) coordinate (btl-1) -- (3.5,1.2,0) coordinate (btr-1) -- (ftr-1) -- (ftl-1) -- cycle;
  \filldraw [lightgray] (flr-1) -- (ftr-1) -- (btr-1) --  (br -| btr-1) -- cycle;
  \node at (4,0.5,5) {$\varepsilon$};
  \coordinate (nA1) at (1.5,2.5,0);
  \coordinate (nB1) at (3.5,2.5,0);
  \coordinate (nA2) at (-1.5,1.2,0);
  \coordinate (nB2) at (-1.5,1.2,5);
  \coordinate (nA3) at (7,1,5);
  \coordinate (nB3) at (7,1.2,5);
  \coordinate (nA4) at (-1.5,1,5);
  \coordinate (nB4) at (-1.5,0,5);
  \Dimline{(nA1)}{(nB1)}[$w$];
  \Dimline{(nA2)}{(nB2)}[$l$];
  \Dimline{(nA3)}{(nB3)};
  \path (nA3) -- (nB3) coordinate [midway] (t) ;
  \node [right=2.5pt of t] {$t$};
  \Dimline{(nA4)}{(nB4)}[$h$];
  \draw [densely dashed, help lines, blend mode=color dodge]  (nB4) -- (flr) (btr-1) -- (nA2)  (nB2) -- (nB3)  (nA4) -- (nA3) (nA1) -- (btl-1) (nB1) -- (btr-1 |- br);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: different version, at least]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate provided clear code. Both solutions, yours and Mikes, are nicely done.