# Fixing arrow angle with shorten >

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have the following minimal example where I use `in` and `out` in combination with `shorten >`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 1.5em}]
\node (a) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (b) at (0, 0.8) {$b$};
\draw[->, shorten > = 3pt] (a) to [out = 45, in = -45] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrowhead angle is wrong]

As you can see, the arrowhead is no longer aligned with the end of the path. Is there a way to change either the angle of the arrowhead, or — ideally — the curvature of the path, such that it comes in at a -45 degree angle at the point 3pt before the node? I would not mind tweaking some angles or control points manually.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/a-looping-edge-with-shorten-that-is-symmetrical-and-points-toward-the-no) is the closest question I could find, but it relates to the `decorations` library which I am not using.

Comment: Consider moving `b` a little bit upper. Maybe at position `(0,1)`.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the nodes is not an option for me.

Comment: Even by `0.2` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, % <--- added
                bending      % <--- added
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 1.5em}]
\node (a) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (b) at (0, 0.8) {$b$};
\draw[-{Straight Barb[bend]}, % <--- changed 
      shorten > = 3pt] (a) to [out = 45, in = -45] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! In my not-so-minimal use case I am using a custom arrow tip to match tikz-cd, but setting `bend` on that arrow tip did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that Zarko's answer is already good, I would like to bring to your attention a different approach that could be or not a possible alternative for you. Using the `looseness` key (described in section 70.3 of the [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)), it is possible to act on the distance of the control points from the start and target coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 1.5em}]
      \node (a) at (0, 0) {$a$};
      \node (b) at (0, 0.8) {$b$};
      \draw[->, shorten > = 3pt] (a) to [out = 45, in = -45, looseness=1.6] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you could use this in combination with `bend`ing the arrow head.

[image]